# multiple ifelse statements

Tags: r, if-statement, conditional-statements

I am attempting to assign values to a column based on conditional statements but the POSIXct format seems to be throwing me off. I have a column of times and would like to assign them to day/night/dawn/dusk with something like this:

```
if(t40636$time>t40636$dawn.b&t40636$time<t40636$dawn.e){
  t40636$time.periods=1
} else {
  if(t40636$time>t40636$mid.day.b&t40636$time<t40636$mid.day.e){
    t40636$time.periods=2
  } else {
    if(t40636$time>t40636$dusk.b&t40636$time<t40636$dusk.e){
      t40636$time.periods=3
    } else {
      if(t40636$time>t40636$mid.night.b&t40636$time<t40636$mid.night.e){
        t40636$time.periods=4
        } else {
          t40636$time.periods=0
        }
    }
  }
}
```

However, this code does not work because of the format of the columns and yields the matrix seen below (only 0s in the time.periods column).

```
     Date Temp..ºC. Depth..m. Light  time time.at.depth dawn.b dawn.e dusk.b
1 2012-06-19     14.47     -21.5   255 15:32             0  01:42  04:42  19:13
2 2012-06-19     16.99     -20.2   255 15:37             5  01:42  04:42  19:13
3 2012-06-19     12.60     -18.8   255 15:41             4  01:42  04:42  19:13
4 2012-06-19     16.36     -17.5   255 15:46             5  01:42  04:42  19:13
5 2012-06-19     16.36     -13.4   255 15:51             5  01:42  04:42  19:13
6 2012-06-19     17.94      -2.7   255 15:56             5  01:42  04:42  19:13
  dusk.e mid.day.b mid.day.e mid.night.b mid.night.e time.periods
1  22:13     10:27     13:27       22:27       01:27            0
2  22:13     10:27     13:27       22:27       01:27            0
3  22:13     10:27     13:27       22:27       01:27            0
4  22:13     10:27     13:27       22:27       01:27            0
5  22:13     10:27     13:27       22:27       01:27            0
6  22:13     10:27     13:27       22:27       01:27            0
```

ifelse yields something close to what I want but I can't do multiple statements with it. Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

```
t40636$time.periods=ifelse(t40636$time>t40636$dawn.b&t40636$time<t40636$dawn.e,1,0)
```

Comment: Your question is really in a `fix my code` format. Rather than making us decipher through your formatting, provide a simplified example of what you're doing and then ask for help.

Comment: Aren't you getting a Warning message? `Warning message: ... the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used`? That is a clue as to what is going on. Perhaps you want the `ifelse` function rather than the `if` statement.

Comment: Why can't you do multiple `ifelse` statements?

Answer (score 0):

The answer to "fix my multiple if-else statements" is nearly always  "Don't use multiple if-else constructions."

The R-language has a very nice `switch` function, and its help page has some excellent examples.

Comment: I agree with you, but this should be a comment.

Comment: @SeñorO  No, I really want this to be an answer, although I should take the time to post some simple example of `switch(x,'a','b','c')`

Comment: Switch isn't vectorized either, and that is the problem here.

Comment: @blindJesse `Vectorize(switch,my.dbase,...)`  is one solution. A simple loop is another.